# Fastest Way to compare if a value is in Range

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a class

```
public class VitalSign
{
    public double? Temprature { get; set; }
    public double? SystolicBP { get; set; }
    public double? DiastolicBP { get; set; }
    public double? PulseRate { get; set; }
    public double? Respirations { get; set; }
}
```

and  a Range class

```
 public  class VitalRange
{
    public Tuple<double,double> TemperatureRange { get; set; }
    public Tuple<double, double> SystolicBPRange { get; set; }
    public Tuple<double, double> DiastolicBPRange { get; set; }
    public Tuple<double, double> RespirationsRange { get; set; }
    public Tuple<double, double> PulseRange { get; set; }
}
```

I have to compare if my property(say temperature) is out of range  compared to VitalRange( Temperature). Can I use a Tuple in this case or can I have a KVP  for ranges?.  I will be comparing a   huge List against VitalRange. What will be the fastest way to check if a property falls within the range.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your problem, It's simple `if`, but you can encapsulate it by using extension methods:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this double? input, Tuple<double, double> range)
{
   if (!input.HasValue)
      return false;
   return input >= range.Item1 && input <= range.Item2;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
VitalRange sampleRanges = ....;
var validTempers = vitalSignList.Where(x=>x.Temprature.IsInRange(sampleRange.VitalRange);
```

I can't think for extremely faster way, but I prefer encapsulation.